# How do i remove myself from this site?

Tags: discussion

I no longer wish to participate as a member of this site, and i wish to remove myself and all of my answers and questions!

Is this possible, please help.

I wish you all good luck on your paths!

Answer (score 3):

For future reference, visit:

https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/help/deleting-account

for instructions on deleting your account.

You can also post a request on https://buddhism.meta.stackexchange.com/ and we will take care of it for you.

In this instance, the process for deletion of your account has now been initiated. In 24 hours, your account will be deleted. If you change your mind in the meantime, please let us know.

Answer (score 1):

Your questions and answers will not be removed or deleted (see also the 'Subscriber Content' section of the [Stack Exchange Network Terms of Service](http://stackexchange.com/legal)), but after your account is deleted they will show as being associated with an anonymous/deleted user account.